# Does full userdata __gc metamethod need to free() it's memory?

Tags: garbage-collection, lua

I have a full userdata in Lua module written in C. The userdata has `__gc()` metamethod, which is called by garbage collector. Does lua interpreter free userdata memory after `__gc()` call, or do I have to `free()` it inside `__gc()`?

Answer (score 8):

You should not free the memory, as you didn't malloc() it yourself; Lua does both for you. In fact, the memory isn't even collected in the same garbage-collection cycle, as section 2.10.1 in the [Lua 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) explains.